# ag-grid-vue: Is there an event which is guaranteed to fire before onGridReady and onFirstDataRendered?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I've just started using ag-grid with vue, and noticed that sometimes onGridReady fires first, and sometimes onFirstDataRendered fires first. I was wondering if there was an event guaranteed to fire before both of those, so that I could set this.gridApi = grid.api once. (I'm currently setting it at the beginning of both as a workaround).

Update: this only seems to happen when the vue component containing the grid is initialized after page load (via a v:if), and not when it is visible on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you missed something I suppose, cuz `onFirstDataRendered` couldn't be executed before `gridReady` - cuz only after initialization (exact grid-ready event) - the grid itself would be ready to proceed.

Here is a hierarchy from [ag-grid doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#properties-and-hierarchy), which sais :

```
GridReadyEvent - will be executed very first.
```

Comment: onFirstDataRendered is definitely being executed first. I have breakpoints which say so. I also get a "this.gridApi" not defined when onFirstDataRendered fires. (Before I put in the workaround redefining it).

Comment: Provide an example on plinkr or stackblitz